# What does this piece of code print infinite number of times?

Tags: c

I would like to know why this piece of code printf char c infinitely:

```
char c;
for (c = 0; c< 256; c++)
printf("Char c=%c\n", c);
```

Thanks

Comment: Because a `char` value is ***always*** less than `256` (provided `CHAR_BIT` is `8` heh heh).

Comment: `char` holds values from 0-255 (or -128-127 when considering the sign bit) ,, so 255+1 wraps back around to 0,, so your condition `c<256` is always true.

Comment: Change the `%c` to `%d`, and the answer should be clear.

Comment: @yano: Neither is true unless we know the target platform.

Comment: @Olaf True.. made the assumption based on his observation what I said is true for his target platform

Comment: @yano: What if OP has a 9 bit/byte platform with signed `char`? Or 8 bit/byte with signed `char` and 1`s complement or sign/magnitude encoding? All allowed by the standard :-)

Comment: @Olaf then what I said is wrong. If the OP is working with such a niche system, then this probably isn't the type of question that gets asked in the first place, at least not without providing that information in the question. It's not way out of line to assume the OP, a member since today, is a beginner working on a vanilla/POSIX 8-bit-char system who just had a lapse (or never knew) about data ranges for `char`. Why are you directing your wrath at my lowly comment, rather than the +3 answer, which basically says the same thing?

Comment: @yano: Because I did not read that answer so far :-) And sometimes looking above the horizon helps see things right.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `CHAR_BIT` is 8 (which it almost always is), a `char` object *cannot* represent a value of 256; signed `char` will max out at 127, while unsigned `char` will max out at 255.

**Signed case**

When `c` is 127 and you add 1, the value "overflows".  Because one's-complement and sign-magnitude representations are still a thing on some oddball architectures, the exact result can vary.  For two's-complement, it will "wrap around" to -128, whereas for one's-complement it wraps around to -127, and for sign-magnitude it becomes -0.

All of these values are less than 256, so the condition `c < 256` is always true.

Because the result can vary based on the platform, the C language definition places no requirements on the compiler to handle signed integer overflow in any particular way - the behavior is left *undefined*, and any result is equally "correct" as far as the language is concerned.  A reasonably smart compiler might be able to detect that the condition will always evaluate to true and issue a warning, and it would be free to do that as far as the language definition is concerned.  Or not.

**Unsigned case**

Unlike the signed case, unsigned integer overflow is well-defined; if `c` is 255 and you add 1, then the result wraps around back to 0.  Again, 0 is less than 256, so `c < 256` will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `char` data type is only one byte long, and therefore can only hold the values `0-255`.

So when `c` is `255` and you do `c++`, it becomes 0.  Thus, `c` is *always* `< 256` in the loop.

Comment: This assumes that a plain `char` is unsigned, which is almost never the case.

Comment: @David Strictly speaking, chat is exactly one byte and can hold `CHAR_BIT` bits, which is _at least_ 8.

Comment: @user3386109: It is so on all ARM systems which are AAPCS compatible and many others. It also is true for many embedded MCUs, e.g. MSP430. Somming up all thoses systems, one can very well say **most** systems use unsigned `char`!

Comment: A byte is not guaranteed to be an octet. A 9 bit signed char would show the same behaviour. Also signed integer overflow invokes undefined behaviour, which can result in much worse behaviour.